# Large list using ScrollView

Tags: android, listview, scrollview

I am creating a layout where I have a large number of items to display and each item contains a layout with an `ImageView`, `EditText` and `TextView`. Ideally, this is perfect candidate for ListView, however, since I have an `EditText`, I can't get focus on it when the user tries to type something. Reading the many posts about this on SO, it seems like there is no clean solution to implement this with ListView.

However, I may have 100s of items to display, and it doesn't seem like a wise idea to directly render all of this on a `ScrollView`. Are there any design patterns for handling this situation?

Comment: the new `RecyclerView` in the support library sounds like something that is exactly what you need: http://antonioleiva.com/recyclerview/

Comment: how about removing the edit from the list? make it a textbox and either add an edit button or on click popup a dialog for edit.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce: Just implemented using RecycleView and it works awesome! Thanks! Not sure how to give you credit for the answer, since it is in a comment.

Comment: I made an answer out of it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you need is the new [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html) that was recently added to the support library. A simple introduction is available [here](http://antonioleiva.com/recyclerview).

The RecyclerView is especially useful because it doesn't have an `onItemClickListener`. People tend to ask "but why doesn't it have one?"

It's actually really smart, exactly because of your use-case: it doesn't steal your focus on clickable items (as you know, the ListView does that), and instead, every click event is delegated to the children's `onClickListener`s.

The example from the specified link (source is the blog of *Antonio Leiva*):

```
public class MyRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyRecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private List<ViewModel> items;
    private int itemLayout;

    public MyRecyclerAdapter(List<ViewModel> items, int itemLayout) {
        this.items = items;
        this.itemLayout = itemLayout;
    }

    @Override public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(itemLayout, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        ViewModel item = items.get(position);
        holder.text.setText(item.getText());
        holder.image.setImageBitmap(null);
        Picasso.with(holder.image.getContext()).cancelRequest(holder.image);
        Picasso.with(holder.image.getContext()).load(item.getImage()).into(holder.image);
        holder.itemView.setTag(item);
    }

    @Override public int getItemCount() {
        return items.size();
    }

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public ImageView image;
        public TextView text;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            image = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.image);
            text = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.text);
        }
    }
}
```

Where on `add` and `remove`:

```
public void add(ViewModel item, int position) {
    items.add(position, item);
    notifyItemInserted(position);
}

public void remove(ViewModel item) {
    int position = items.indexOf(item);
    items.remove(position);
    notifyItemRemoved(position);
}
```

And initialization:

```
RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.list);
recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);  // use this setting to improve performance if you know that changes
                                     // in content do not change the layout size of the RecyclerView
recyclerView.setAdapter(new MyRecyclerAdapter(list, R.layout.item));
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
```

Requires dependency:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.+'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try to use RecycleView. It works better with a large data sets. 
https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html

"The RecyclerView widget is a more advanced and flexible version of ListView. This widget is a container for displaying large data sets that can be scrolled very efficiently by maintaining a limited number of views. Use the RecyclerView widget when you have data collections whose elements change at runtime based on user action or network events."